# Using Shell cmd in excel VBA returns error 53

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I am having problems executing an instruction using the shell command in Excel VBA while it's running fine through Windows CMD. the purpose of the command is to close the program "PN" and then reset used the licenses.
for closing the program "PN" I'm using the command:

`Shell ("taskkill /f /im pn4.exe")`, which works fine.

But for resetting the used license I use the following command:

`Shell ("pnserver flush && timout /t 100")`, which does not work.

But when I try to reset the license using windows CMD and just typing in the command `"pnserver flush"` it works just fine and the licenses have been reset.

also when I try to execute the following command it doesn't work:

`Shell ("cmd.exe /c pnserver flush && timeout /t 100")`

The code used to work properly but there are issues that may have arisen since an excel update. I tried to run it on an other PC which worked fine. I'm currently using version 2019MSO (16.0.13001.20266) 32-bits.

Comment: I expect is has something to do with the double-ampersand ... but then you've tried it with cmd.exe /c. How about putting doublequotes around the commands after the /c, viz `vbDoubleQuote = """" : Shell("cmd.exe  /c " & vbDoubleQuote & "pnserver flush && timout /t 100" & vbDoubleQuote)`

Comment: Also error 53 is "file not found", so is it really "timout" or is it "timeout"?

Comment: The `Shell` command is VBA not VBScript.

Comment: ... are you able to run the `pnserver` command in command prompt? (I tried, but my computer does not understand `pnserver`)